# Want to reset integers using virtual class function

Tags: class, polymorphism, virtual

The function I want works within the class butt won't apply to main. Must maintain the initial                                                    (Entity *entity = new Nummchange(flarb);)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


 class Entity
 {
public:

Entity(){}
~Entity(){}

virtual int reset(int NUMM) = NULL;

protected:
private:
};

class Nummchange : public Entity
{
public:

Nummchange(int NUMM);
~Nummchange();

int reset(int NUMM);


protected:
private:
int numm;
};

Nummchange::Nummchange(int NUMM)
{   
}

Nummchange::~Nummchange()
{
}

int Nummchange::reset(int NUMM)
{   
numm = 50;
NUMM = numm;
std::cout << "\nnumm+++++++"<< numm << "\n" << std::endl;   
return numm;    
}




int main()
{
int flarb = 50;
Entity *entity = new Nummchange(flarb);
while (flarb >= 0)
{
    flarb--;
    cout << flarb;
    if(flarb == 0)
    {
        entity->reset(flarb);
        std::cout << "flarb+++++++"<< flarb << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Success is if the while loop continues perpetually.

Answer (score 0):

`int reset(int NUMM);` method should take reference of integer type as below.

```
int reset(int &NUMM);
```

Make sure that you change the parameter to be reference of integer in all the three places of the method use in the program.